# Setting up a cluster with workload distribution

Tags: linux, load-balancing, kubernetes, cluster, slurm

I want to setup a server cluster which can keep by servers as busy as possible while still giving fair compute time to everyone. I have setup a basic Kubernetes setup but the issue is that if some user releases a pod which can parallelize upto say 256 cores, but the machines have maximum of 96 cores in them, then the workload won't split onto different machines. Rather the workload will slow down on 96 cores itself. I want soomething which can split the pods onto different machines so that all the cores in the cluster are kept busy.

Comment: A pod can't be split. You can create multiple copies of a pod and limit its resource utilisation.

Comment: This "keep by servers as busy as possible" is totally dependent on the workload/application how many resources it wants to consume. You also want to reserve 20% for the operating system and related services, you don't want a crashing cluster. I think you need to look into a sort of servicebus where you have quene which you can fill to the max

Comment: What kinds of jobs you are expected to be running? I am thinking about interactive vs batch, thousands of shortish (< 1hr) vs giant jobs going for days. Any high RAM or GPU jobs? Programs using MPI? Computations where IO could be a bottle neck? Scheduler is one thing but a high speed networking and a reliable NAS may be something to check out first

Comment: Jobs will mostly be a large number (thousands) of single-threaded processes that individially run for 15-20 mins (on a single core). No RAM or GPU intensive jobs. IO won't be a bottleneck either.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to use [topologySpreadConstraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/#topologyspreadconstraints-field) wherein you can spread the pods across the cluster among the nodes. This depends as well with the number of replica on your workload/deployments.

I think you need to let the scheduler distribute the loads on the nodes which is the purpose of kubernetes deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may either use some old workstation or (better) pinch out one machine out of your current Kubernetes cluster and convert it into one machine `SLURM` cluster just to get things up and running. The fairly typical route is to use RPM-based distro (nowadays `Rocky Linux` or `Alma Linux`) but `Debian` should work fine as well. Once `sbatch` is working start setting up few power user accounts, mount the NFS(?) drives install the most commonly used user software (check `spack`, `apptainer` and `conda`). Give yourself some time to iron out the "bare bones" configuration issues before moving to more advanced issues like `cgroups` or proper `slurmdb` accounting.

Even with 20mins jobs make sure that these are optimized whenever feasible. At times simply installing `pigz`, `zstd`, `pypy3`, `ripgrep`, `duckdb` can have immediate effect.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to setup a server cluster which can keep by servers as busy as
> possible while still giving fair compute time to everyone

That's what the Kubernetes scheduler does.

> I have setup a basic Kubernetes setup but the issue is that if some
> user releases a pod which can parallelize upto say 256 cores, but the
> machines have maximum of 96 cores in them, then the workload won't
> split onto different machines

A pod is a atomic unit of work and cannot be split.

> I want soomething which can split the pods onto different machines so
> that all the cores in the cluster are kept busy.

That is not possible. A pod will be scheduled on a single server and cannot be "split".

I think the word you are looking for is "spread" here. You want to spread yor workload among many servers.

You and the users likely share responsibilities and thus have to work together to correctly configure the application and the platform to work smoothly.

The application(s) running in a pod need to be correctly configure to use only a certain amount of compute. You can either configure the application to use only a certain number of threads or track CPU time.

On top of that, you MUST configure the pod with resource [requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/). That way the Kubernetes schedule has more information to know where the pod will fit (or not). The Linux kernel (through cgroups) will enforce the CPU limits and throttle the process.

My suggestion is to work with developers to correctly configure their deployments that have pods with resources that will fit your hardware platform.

If you want to prevent them from ever deploying a workload that will create problems or malfunction in terms of resource allocation, you can deploy something like [Kyverno](https://kyverno.io/), [OPA](https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/) or even improve your CI/CD pipelines to catch these errors.

As a research point for you, if you really want to have a platform that will grab workloads and load balance them among many servers seamlessly, look for [HPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-performance_computing) solutions. Your developers will need to be heavily involved though to use the proper libraries for this.